# confused with loops in php

Tags: php, loops

Am a bit confused with the loops in php. Actually i have two tables. A student table with details of a student like id,name,class,phone_number etc and an attendance table which contain attndenc_id, status(0 if present, 1 if absent), student_id and date. Now i want to select all the student_ids with status 1 with today's date from attendance table and with that student_id i want to get the phone_number of absenties only. For that i have done the followings:

```
    $check  =   array(  'date' => date('Y-m-d') , 'status' => '1' );
    $absenties = $this->db->get_where('attendance' , $check)->result_array(); 
    foreach ($absenties as $row3){
          $reciever_phone = $row['phone'];
         }
```

But Iam getting the same phone number of a single student.May be iam going through a wrong approach. Please help me to go in a right way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$reciever_phone  = array();foreach ($absenties as $row3){
          $reciever_phone[] = $row['phone'];
         }   echo "<pre/>";print_r($reciever_phone);`

Comment: i tried this now. but getting the same value throughout the array. like Array
(
    [0] => 1234567890
    [1] => 1234567890
)but my table doesnt contain any duplicate values

Comment: Each time the loop runs, it is overriding the `$reciever_phone` string with the phone of the user being looped. You'll end up with the number of the last student. You should store them in an array like `$reciever_phone[] = $row['phone'];` instead.

Comment: @Ajzz  then your query is not accurate to  fetch your desired result.